# How do you "accept" a file upload in Mule 3.8? (Not deprecated)

Tags: mule

How does one upload a file using an API in Mule 3.8? Can someone provide an example for a multipart/form-field POST using an example log file? Here's an old way but the connector is deprecated.

```
<http:connector name="httpConnector" doc:name="HTTP\HTTPS">
    <service-overrides
        messageFactory="org.mule.transport.http.HttpMultipartMuleMessageFactory" />
</http:connector>
```

I'm testing a process API that creates an import and then "will" call another service to upload itself. I'm modeling my own file upload using Mule and I can't seem to get anything to work. I have a Spring Boot servlet that uses Apache Commons Upload but I would prefer to have my upload prototype in Mule with my real projects until our Mule servers are installed.